# draw basic shapes in excel automatically

Tags: excel

Excel experts :
I have a task to convert a table to a diagram in Excel.
e.g. the table looks like :
[my source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oEhq.png)

and the result I expect is a diagram in Excel automatically, maybe it can be done by some scripts :
[my expect auto generated diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeZ53.png)

It will be nice if the solution can work in both Windows and Linux OS.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel's own VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) by adding a button to the sheet and attaching a macro to it. This macro can read your table and create shapes, all using the VBA code.

In Developer Tab >> Insert >> Form Controls >> Button
In the dialog that comes up, click New to assign a macro to the button's click event. Put your code inside that macro. You have to write the **some scripts** that you mentioned.

Comment: Whether the VBA scripts can work in the OpenOffice in Linux ?

Comment: OpenOffice does not have Excel, it has the Calc program. I think Calc uses a different scripting language: OpenOffice Basic